# angularjs directive scope '@' options

Tags: angularjs

I met a problem when I used directive of angularjs.
Here is the problem:

directives.js:

```
    var directives = angular.module('directives', []);

    directives.directive('list', ['$templateCache', function() {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: [
            names: '@'
        ],
        template: '<div>'+
                  '<div ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</div>'+
                  '{{names}}'+
                  '</div>',
        replcae: true
    }]);
```

example.html:

```
    ......
    <div ng-controller="nameCtrl">
        <list names="{{names}}"></list>
    </div>
    ......
```

controllers.js

```
    var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);

    controller.controller('nameCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.names = ['foo', 'bar'];
    }]);
```

But when I opened the example.html,it only printed:

```
   ["foo","bar"]
```

not what I supposed to :

```
    foo
    bar
    ["foo","bar"]
```

So,what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@` is used to pass a **string** to the directive. So your array is transformed to JSON by angular, and the JSON string is passed to the directive.

If you want to pass an object or an array, use `=`.